# FullCalendar.io - how to use business hours to prevent dateclick on certain times

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using https://fullcalendar.io, specifically the dateClick function as below

```
dateClick: function(info) {
                //alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
                calendar.changeView('timeGridDay', info.dateStr);
                console.log(info);
                if (info.view.type == 'timeGridDay') {
                    date = info.dateStr;
                    var modal = $('#add-event-modal');
                    modal.modal('show');
                    $(modal).find('input[name=parade_start]').val(info.dateStr.substring(0, 10) + ' ' + info.dateStr.substring(11, 19));
                }
            },
```

I am also using business hours between 9am and 5pm. At the moment, A user can click on any time within the view to pop the modal but I want the modal only to be opened if they click on the business hours.

Please advise - not sure if this is possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callback (instead of dateClick) to detect user selections.

Once you've done that, you can then set the [selectConstraint](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectConstraint) option to "businessHours", which automatically stops people from selecting times outside the stated business hours.

e.g.:

```
selectable: true,
select: function(info) {
  alert("selected " + info.startStr + " to " + info.endStr);
},
businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4], // Monday - Thursday
  startTime: "10:00", // a start time (10am in this example)
  endTime: "18:00" // an end time (6pm in this example)
},
selectConstraint: "businessHours"
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxGpJXG

Answer (score 1):

```
  dateClick: (info) => {
    info.jsEvent.preventDefault();

    if (info.jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-non-business')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Try this ;)